# The positions of IIFEs (immediately invoked function expressions) of JS cause an unexpected error

Tags: javascript, iife

The following code including an IIFE causes an error in Node(node: v8.6.0) environment.

```
function A(){}
A()
(function(){})()
```

> ​​​​​​A(...) is not a function​​

This error information is confusing for me.

If I change the position of IIFE, the code runs successfully in Node.

```
(function(){})()
function A(){}
A()
```

I have searched the answer on google but didn't find why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this snippet:

```
function A(){}
A()
(function(){})()
```

you are starting third line with `(` which is interpreted by JS parser as a function invocation. In this case [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) lets you down.

You could try this instead:

```
function A(){}
A(); // <-----
(function(){})()
```

or

```
function A(){}
A()
;(function(){})()
```

both will fix the problem.

Avoid staring line with `(` or `[`.

Comment: Splendid. Your answer solved my problem.

Comment: assigning the result to a variable also solves the problem. const test = (function(){})()

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `;` you can get around this.

Expressions should end with `;` to avoid this problem:

```
function A(){}
A();
(function(){})()
```